# Typescript - getting tslint error on createReducer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, tslint

I created a simple reducer as part of ngRx, got the below error for the `on()` method.

[image]

also, got some errors in the reducer_creator.d.ts file:

[image]

[image]

Further, Here is my package.json ngrx and typescript versions:

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^11.0.1",
"@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.0.1",
"typescript": "~3.1.6"
```

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NgRx v11 expects TypeScript 4 to be used.
https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v11